# Is this asbestos? (Insulation, transit pipe, wall board)

Tags: asbestos, old-house

These pictures are from a house I just purchased in Western NY. The house was built in 1950 and I believe there are gypsum boards with plaster and lathe over them. Pipe is above a 1944 Pennco boiler. Others are from around house and walls.

Comment: Here is one from basement https://s.amsu.ng/D9qRFYChKfYN

Comment: https://s.amsu.ng/0DeBh8zeDYRN outside bottom of post on porch.

Comment: https://s.amsu.ng/4ho3F3FW77lN basement wall

Comment: https://s.amsu.ng/BiAxUARMUsvN sanded wall area

Comment: https://s.amsu.ng/DaBbpRDezLyN back of area sanded

Comment: Welcome. Your images belong in your question, not down here in comments. Please revise to correct that, and [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, it's virtually impossible to tell from photographs if something does or does not contain asbestos, the only way to tell for sure is to take small samples of it and sent it to a lab to be tested. Anything else is not worth the paper is is (not) written on...